# Adding DFP Script to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am playing with Wordpress 3 for the first time and had a quick question.

I am placing ads on a site and wondered the best practice to add in the script. The code that Google generates is in 2 parts, one for the  of the page and one where the ad should go

The head code is in the form

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-123123");
GS_googleEnableAllServices();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-123123", "300x250_Ad");
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>
```

Then the code for the ad is:

```
<!-- ca-pub-123123/300x250_Ad -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
GA_googleFillSlot("300x250_A");
</script>
```

I downloaded a plugin Advertising Manager that allows me to add ads into the page but only seems to allow putting in one block of code. I can add all the code joined up but if I want to add other ad positions later it is not the best...

I can't go into my Theme and add the code in there, as I am using Multiple Sites the code will need to difer from site to site, is there something very simple I am missing to add stuff into the  and then I can use Advertising Manager to display the individual ad code...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the the [AdSense-Deluxe WordPress Plugin](http://www.acmetech.com/blog/2005/07/26/adsense-deluxe-wordpress-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the plugin has a bug, the shortcode you're using is calling a function which is directly outputting the code for DFP (which is called when wordpress is preparing the page content, hence it appearing all at once at the top) instead of returning it to be inserted throughout the content.